# How to keep <select> dropdown open to test styles on <option> in firebug?

Tags: html, css, firebug

How to keep `<select>` dropdown open to test styles on  in firebug?

I'm trying to styling `<option>`

```
<select class="select">
    <option selected>Select</option>
    <option>Blue</option>
    <option >Red</option>
    <option>Green</option>
    <option>Yellow</option>
    <option>Brown</option>
</select>
```

But every time i need to open and see what's happening after changing css in firebug. I know it doesn't take much time to open an see the result.

But I'm just curious to know if there is any trick to keep the dropdown open

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Make it multiple enabled.

```
<select class="select" multiple="multiple">
    <option selected>Select</option>
    <option>Blue</option>
    <option >Red</option>
    <option>Green</option>
    <option>Yellow</option>
    <option>Brown</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Sadly this changes the select box to a list with multiple selection and it doesn't have a drop down any more.