# How to Keep basic Dropdown Open with Select?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```
<select name="cars" id="cars">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

**how to keep the select options open by deafult**

Comment: You can't with the standard control. You will need to use a third party select element replacement library for that, such as Chosen or Select2

Comment: May I ask you why you use a `<select>`, whose aim is to create a _drop-down_ list, instead of check-boxes or radio buttons, if you want to keep it open?

Comment: I'm unsure what you want to achieve exactly. However, have you considered using the [multiple attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8430597/how-to-keep-select-dropdown-open-to-test-styles-on-option-in-firebug)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Open Select using Javascript/jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048213/open-select-using-javascript-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in my comment, displaying a `<select>` element that stays open does not make a lot of sense, as the `<select>` element aim is specifically to create a drop-down list.

Anyway, if you want all your options to be visible, you can use the `size` attribute and set it equal to the number of options available.

```html
<select name="cars" id="cars" size="4">
   <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
   <option value="saab">Saab</option>
   <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
   <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Or, if you do not want to see the scrollbar:

```html
<select name="cars" id="cars" size="4" style="overflow-y: hidden;">
   <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
   <option value="saab">Saab</option>
   <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
   <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant on the native select but keeping it open it defeats the purpose of using a select maybe using a radio input serve you better.

see mozilla doc for an example https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio

Answer (score -1):

Do it to multiple!

Example:

```
<select name="cars" id="cars" multiple="multiple">
   <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
   <option value="saab">Saab</option>
   <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
   <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This doesn't work if you only want to allow a single selection though.

Comment: He don't told what he really want.